# How to use wildcard in mysql query?

Tags: mysql

Hi I want to find out one way to do string search in MySQL query (with wildcard)

In a db table known as "table1", I have the following records (serial, text1)

| serial | text1 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Building in New York |
| 2 | Building in Paris |
| 3 | New York tall Building |
| 4 | Small New York Building |
| 5 | Building in Singapore |

I want to search the records which contain the string "New York Building" (I mean the result should be records containing "New", "York" and "Building") I have attempted something like

```
select * from table1 where text1 like '%New%York%Building%'
```

But only record 3 and record 4 show up (New York tall Building, Small New York Building), but record 1 (Building in New York) does not . This has caused some problem because some users really will type "New York building" as input string and expect that records like "Building in New York" or "A good Building in New York" will appear in the search result.

What is the way to do it in MySQL query ? Thank you.

Comment: Best way is to use a full text search engine and not mysql. Alternate `where text1 like '%new%' and text1 like '%york%' and text1 like '%building%'`

Comment: *I have attempted something like* This condition checks strict relative posession of the words in interest.

Comment: @danblack Thank you ! You've provided very valuable advice !

Comment: Note that danblack's solution assumes that the word 'building' appears in fewer than half the rows of the data set

Comment: why does danblack's solution have such restriction ? I just tried his solution and it works flawlessly.

Comment: There's no restriction in 'use a full text search engine'. The reason I said this is because the `where` clause suggested will be a full table scan and it doesn't scale, and it does match a users expectations. So focus on *not using mysql* here and *use a full text search engine* e.g. [solr](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/)